# How to access relationship in laravel without foreach?

Tags: php, laravel-4, eloquent

I am new to laravel and OOP in php.
I am tring to iterate through Eloquent object but i think i have not the good method.

For example : Categorie Model :

```
class Categorie extends Eloquent {

protected $table = 'categorie';
protected $timestamp = true;
protected $fillable = array('id_parent');

public function children() {

return $this->hasMany('Categorie','id_parent','id');
}

public function traduction() {

return $this->hasMany('Categorie_Langue','id_categorie','id');

}


}
```

Controller index :

```
public function index()
{

    $categorie = Categorie::
    whereNull('id_parent')
    ->has('traduction')
    ->with('traduction')
    ->get()
    ;
    return ($categorie);
}
```

return this :

`[{"id":3,"id_parent":null,"created_at":"2014-08-08 07:04:57","updated_at":"2014-08-08 07:04:57","deleted_at":null,"traduction":[{"id":1,"id_categorie":3,"id_langue":1,"nom":"MEUBLES"}]},{"id":4,"id_parent":null,"created_at":"2014-08-08 07:07:05","updated_at":"2014-08-08 07:07:05","deleted_at":null,"traduction":[{"id":2,"id_categorie":4,"id_langue":1,"nom":"MEUBLES"}]},{"id":6,"id_parent":null,"created_at":"2014-08-08 11:27:11","updated_at":"2014-08-08 11:27:11","deleted_at":null,"traduction":[{"id":4,"id_categorie":6,"id_langue":1,"nom":"DECORATIONS"}]}]`

Exactly what i need but i want to access directly to traduction like this ;

```
echo $categorie->traduction->nom;
```

but i got this error :

```
Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$traduction
```

How to iterate through categories with traduction in object oriented, i can achieve with foreach in foreach but seems not the best practice ?

Thanks for help,

Comment: Ill never know why using `$categorie->traduction->nom;` resulted in a collections error, becuase the output you present is in json, and therefore is vague. Try var_dumping catagorie and put it in the question, and id be able to help you figure out why the your command is resulting in an error.

Comment: You can't access `->nom` since it's single `Traduction` property, while `traduction` is a collection (because the relation is `hasMany`). So use `lists` to get `nom` properties of all the items in that collection.

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
$categorie = Categorie::
whereNull('id_parent')
->has('traduction')
->with('traduction')
->get()->toArray();
```

then use do:

```
$childArray = array_fetch(YOUR_ARRAY, 'traduction.nom');
```

<strike>this is a rough sketch, test appropriately.</strike> I Decided to Test It:

```
$array = array(
    array(
        "id"=>3,
        "id_parent"=>null,
        "created_at"=>"2014-08-08 07:04:57",
        "updated_at"=>"2014-08-08 07:04:57",
        "deleted_at"=>null,
            "traduction"=> array(
                "id"=>1,
                "id_categorie"=>3,
                "id_langue"=>1,
                "nom"=>"MEUBLES"
            )
        ),
    array(
        "id"=>3,
        "id_parent"=>null,
        "created_at"=>"2014-08-08 07:04:57",
        "updated_at"=>"2014-08-08 07:04:57",
        "deleted_at"=>null,
            "traduction"=> array(
            "id"=>1,
            "id_categorie"=>3,
            "id_langue"=>1,
            "nom"=>"MEUBLES"
        )
    )
);

$childArray = array_fetch($array, 'traduction.nom');
print_r($childArray);
```

Outputs:

```
Array ( [0] => MEUBLES [1] => MEUBLES )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:
    echo $categorie->traduction->lists('nom');

Hope it will help! G

Comment: isn't `->lists()` apart of the laravel query builder? if so, that wont work.

Comment: Nope it is a part of Illuminate\Support\Collection
$categorie->traduction()->lists('nom') would be a part of query builder.

Comment: look at the comment i put in the question, coworker looked at his code and noticed the thing we both missed: laravel isnt seeing "traduction" as a proper collection object.

Answer (score 0):

You wanna get traductions of categories where("parent_id", "=", NULL); right?

Then you should able to do this

```
    $categories = Categorie::all();
    foreach($categories as $category)
{
     $categories->load(array('traduction'=>function($q){
$q->where('Categorie.parent_id', NULL);
}))
}
    return $traductions;
```

You could also try with `with`

```
return Categorie::with(array('traduction'=>function($q){
$q->where('Categorie.parent_id', NULL);
}))->get();
```

post your results after trying these..